# Inserting data to SDF with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, linq, sdf

I am making a WinForm project in visual studio 2010 sp1. I am using a local database (.sdf). I want to access the local database file via LINQ. I read a post in search for this and found out. I have to make a dbml file usng SqlMetal.exe from Visual Studio Command Prompt. I made the file and imported it in my project. But I don't know how to add new record to in the database table via LINQ. I know that inserting to database table via LINQ is quite easy like

```
db.Users.Add(myUserObject);
```

But I can't find the Add method in the dropdown list that intellisense shows. What am I missing?

Comment: Any specific reason to use VS2010? And doesn't it have built-in tooling for creating a LINQ-to-SQL context? I don't remember, but in current versions it's somewhere under "add new item - data".

Comment: I tried using a local db as datasource in VS2015 but I couldn't find any template for this so I had to shift to VS2010

Comment: I'm sure you can use localdb with VS2015. Explain what you're trying to achieve and what you tried.

Comment: You should be able to use the [SQLite / SQL Server Compact Toolbox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.SQLServerCompactSQLiteToolbox) to generate the Linq to SQL data context to any modern version of Visual Studio.  It is under the "Code Generation" option of the Data Connections context (right-click) menu.